# On amazon is it possible to see how many of X product a seller has sold?

Tags: amazon

On amazon is it possible to see how many of X product a seller has sold? In a similar way to how this can be done on eBay?

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, which I think is by design. Why? Not really sure..

There is a bestsellers page : https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers/zgbs

That's the closest I have ever seen.